# When I write moof box from mp4, the ASCII code is reversed

Tags: c, video, ascii, mp4, endianness

I am trying to extract the 'moof' box from movie box in isobmff foramt.

```
// It is assumed that the movie box contains fragment data.
ISOMovie moov;
MP4MovieFragmentAtomPtr moof;

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("test_moof_mdat.m4v","w");
movie = (MP4PrivateMovieRecordPtr)moov;
if((movie->moovAtomPtr)->type ==MP4MovieFragmentAtomType)
{
   // movie fragment box 
   moof = (MP4MovieFragmentAtomPtr)movie->moovAtomPtr;
   
   // calculate `moof` box size
   movie->moovAtomPtr->calculateSize(movie->moovAtomPtr);
}
fwrite(moof,moof->size,1,fp2);
```

When I write moof box from mp4, the ASCII code is reversed.
[image]

As you can see, the ASCII code is reversed.
Are the ASCII code and size of the mp4 box in big-endian format?

(*ref : My Computer Cpu : Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6238R CPU @ 2.20GHz. )

Comment: Endianness doesn't make sense for strings, so the question makes no sense. Are you actually writing 0x6DF6F66? Only if you're writing a number would endianness come into play.

Comment: "As you can see," I don't see the string `"moof"` in your code snippet. As we do not see what you are writing, we cannot see if the result is reversed or not.

Comment: Thanks for Comments. @ikegami , As you commented, endianness doesn't matter.
Using Internal Function `serialize` `66 6F 6F 6D` changes to `6D 6F 6F 66`

Comment: What internal function `serialize` are you talking about?

Comment: I'm using isobmff Library. (https://github.com/MPEGGroup/isobmff)   
serialize Function:   
https://github.com/MPEGGroup/isobmff/blob/2a0e1a3690efb4553defca31caf347013f1eb9e1/IsoLib/libisomediafile/src/ESDAtom.c#L44   
When i use this function, It works.   
And Every Atom has common things like   
MP4_BASE_ATOM:    
https://github.com/MPEGGroup/isobmff/blob/2a0e1a3690efb4553defca31caf347013f1eb9e1/IsoLib/libisomediafile/src/MP4Atoms.h#L182

I think that when I use atom to handle(buffer or file), it needs serialize. 
Thank you for answering even though the explanation was insufficient.

Answer (score 2):

> *"Are the ASCII codes and size of the MP4 box written in big-endian format?"*

Yes. All data for the MP4 structure (atoms, values, etc) is expected to be written in Big Endian.

From a quick research it seems your used library does actually write **Big-Endian** for MP4 output. It also allows [adding PCM audio into MP4](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3AMPEGGroup%2Fisobmff+ENDIAN_FORMAT_FLAG_LITTLE&type=code) and that's the only time it deals with Little-Endian code.

It is possible that the problem is in how **fwrite()** itself works.
The library might not be doing anything wrong.

**Possible Solutions:**

**1.** Trying setting your `fopen` output to be in **binary** mode **"wb"** (not just **"w"**). 
If lucky, it might be enough to get data in Big-Endian format. Check if the output is now fixed?

```
fp = fopen("test_moof_mdat.m4v","wb");
```

**2.** You might need to create a custom function to convert the endianness of each 16-bit, 24-bit, or 32-bit integer. If you don't know how, then check this article as a starting point:

https://developer.ibm.com/articles/au-endianc/ 
(especially this part: ***"Listing 4. Forcing a byte order"***).

PS: It's not clear if the `moof =` part (of your code) is giving you an array of byte values (*eg:* `uint32_t`) or not. I mean, is it feasible to manually reverse the integers?

**3.** A final solution is to just **manually extract the atom** yourself from the file (or bytes stream). I can expand on this part later if you need some help (no C++ here to test), but the short version of the concept is:

- Get your MOOV bytes to a point where you can read them one-by-one using a **While** loop.
- Search by incrementing `idx` forwards through the **uint_8** array's slots (*eg:* **read single bytes**).
- If a slot has a byte with matching start value then check if the other next 3 bytes also match.
- If all matching, you have now found start position of the "moof" text in your `moof` atom.
- From new `pos_moof`, go backwards -4 bytes, then read the `size` as a 32-bit Big-Endian uint.
- Extract a new Array from input bytes (start from `pos_moof`, length is `(size + 4)` etc).

Below is a quick *"search for bytes sequence"* example using pseudo-code...

```
//### about the required vars...

byte[] my_MOOV_Bytes_Array //# provides input byte values (could be an Array or FileStream, etc)

int pos_idx = 0; //# for the index (pos) within the bytes

//### search process is simple with a While loop...

while (true)
{
    //# end While loop if reached end of bytes Array
    if( pos_idx >= my_MOOV_Bytes_Array.length ) { break; }
    
    //# find "m"
    if( my_MOOV_Bytes_Array[ pos_idx ] == 0x6D )                
    {
        if( 
            ( my_MOOV_Bytes_Array[ pos_idx + 1 ] == 0x6F ) &&   //# find "o"
            ( my_MOOV_Bytes_Array[ pos_idx + 2 ] == 0x6F ) &&   //# find "o"
            ( my_MOOV_Bytes_Array[ pos_idx + 3 ] == 0x66 )      //# find "f"
        )
        {
            cout << "MOOF atom found at : " << pos_idx << endl;
            break; //# or can Return pos_idx if used inside a search function
        }
    }
    
    pos_idx++; //# just keep incrementing...
}
```